# Uploading image as profile picture

Tags: ios, image

My app has to integrate `uploading image to set it as profile picture`. The thing is all the images has to be `stored in web services`.

As web service has not been yet created. what is the `best way to store images for temporary purpose` so that i can integrate it easily when i have been provided with the backend.Sample tutorials can be helpful

Comment: Try with NSbundle OR Sqlite....

Comment: Use imgur its got very easy public api and lets you get the data over the wire rather then dummying the calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best idea is to use FTWCache (https://github.com/FTW/FTWCache) and cache it localy. Later, using webservice, you can still use your already written cache mechanism to implement NSURLConnection with caching. Profit! ;-)